# Sending wordpress email after registration fails if html template is included in $message variable

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email

I'm trying to send an email to the user after successful registration with a custom form. Everything works fine, the user is logged in and the email is sent.

Here is the working code, the email is sent successfully:

```
// Other code....

if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
      wp_send_json_error( 'Errore durante la creazione dell\'utente.' );
   } else {
      // Send user email
      $to = $email;
      $subject = 'Welcome Text';
      $message = 'Hello ' . $username . ',<br><br>Welcome Text etc... <br><br>Other Text,<br>Other Text...';
      $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
      wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

      // Send success message
      wp_send_json_success( 'User successfully created, redirect...' );
   }
```

What I want to do is have a custom email template and not plain text like in the code above. So I created an html file titled signup-email.html and stored its path in the $message variable to send the template instead of the text.

So, below the code that doesn't work, the email is not sent:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
      wp_send_json_error( 'Errore durante la creazione dell\'utente.' );
   } else {
      // Send user email
      $to = $email;
      $subject = 'Welcome Text';
      $message = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/signup-email.html' );
      $message = str_replace( '{{USERNAME}}', $username, $message );
      $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
      wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

      // Send success message
      wp_send_json_success( 'User successfully created, redirect...' );
   }
```

The signup-email.html file is located in the templates folder of my plugin, the path is as follows: /wp-content/plugins/custom-login/templates/signup-email.html

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to wordpress and trying to figure something out about user registration/login. But here it is not clear to me why the email is not sent.

Comment: ___Doesn't work___ Is really not a helpful description of any issue. What does happen, what doesn't happen, do you get any error messages, does the email get sent but without the template ....?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I managed to find a solution.
Basically I had to use the ob_start() function to start an output buffer, so that the template output is saved in a variable.

The ob_get_contents() function is used instead to retrieve the output of the buffer. Finally, the ob_end_clean() function is used to purge the buffer.

Here is the updated code for anyone having the same difficulty as me.

```
 // Send user email
      $to = $email;
      $subject = 'Welcome Text';
      ob_start();
      include_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/mts-custom-login/templates/welcome-email.php' );
      $message = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
      wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```